# Is there a Chrome/Firefox extension that can edit response body from a POST?

Tags: chrome, firefox

The title says pretty much everything.

But let me give you an example here:

**REQUEST HEADER**
[image: Request Header]

**REQUEST BODY**
[image: Request Body]

**RESPONSE HEADER** 
[image: Response Header]

**RESPONSE BODY**
[image: Response Body]

And all I want is changing the `valid` property to `true` instead of `false` in the **response body**.

I already tried Tamper Data, but somehow I can't edit the body of the response.

Is there a **existing extension** that can do that for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tamper Data should be able to do this (and it's my usual tool). What obstacle did you encounter?

Comment: @Kodiologist Well I couldn't install it to my Firefox. But with V3.5 the website isn't functional

Comment: I don't know whether you mean version 3.5 of Firefox or of Tamper Data, but either would be very old. Try upgrading.

Comment: @Kodiologist 3.5 of Firefox. I have the newest version of Firefox aswell but they aren't compatible with Tamper Data

Comment: @Kodiologist I am successfully able to install Tamper Data on Firefox 15.0 with my website fully working but still: I can't find a way to edit that response data. I can only edit requests

Comment: I'm sorry; I misread your question as being about request bodies instead of response bodies. I don't know why I was so dense, considering how clear you made it. But yeah, probably you can't find any way to edit responses because that's not usually something that's done client-side for debugging. You could try inserting some JavaScript to set `used` before the JSON response is processed in whatever way it's usually processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a distant solution, but try to look at Postman. There is a version  based on Google Chrome, which unfortunately will be deprecated in late 2017.